# Why is this SQL query not retrieving any data?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to get a `DataTable` containing Houses in a specific city with rooms between x and y.

I'm using this SQL query:

```
"SELECT * FROM Houses WHERE City = '" + Cities.Text + 
"' AND Rooms BETWEEN '" + MinRooms.Text + "' AND '" + MaxRooms.Text + "'"
```

The controls are dropdownlists in ASP.NET.

When I remove it and leave only the "between rooms" it works.

What should I look for? Everything seems to be correct.

Comment: Remove ' (apostrophes) used with BETWEEN - just in case Rooms is a numeric column.

Comment: As an important aside, your code is vulnerable to **SQL injection attacks** (Google it! Very important!). To avoid this you need to implement something called **parameterized queries** (Google it as well).

Comment: Put a debug breakpoint the line after you build the SQL string and take a look at the query. Does it look like you expect it to? Also, note that building queries as string from user input can lead to SQL Injection; please use [parameterized queries](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp.html) instead.

Comment: Your approach of using the .Text property directly is VULNERABLE to SQL injection.  You should parameterize your query. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131332/sql-injection-attack-on-asp-registration-form-pages.

Comment: thanks for the replies.
i already tried removing the apostrophes, it didnt work.
if this query supposed to work - i guess i have to look deeper into the code.. :(
about the injection, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Did you output the query text after you dangerously injected the form field values? Did you try running that query directly, outside of the application?

Comment: @SystemDown Love your advice, and your user handle :)

Comment: @Shiva - It's an important bit of advice I wished someone had given me when I was starting up myself :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume `Rooms` is an `int` column, therefore you need to remove the apostrophes which are for text columns. But you should use sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection anyway:

```
string sql = @"SELECT h.* FROM Houses h 
              WHERE City = @City 
              AND Rooms BETWEEN @MinRooms AND @MaxRooms";
var table = new DataTable();
using(var con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con))
{
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", Cities.Text);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinRooms",int.Parse(MinRooms.Text));
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaxRooms",int.Parse(MaxRooms.Text));
    da.Fill(table);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Houses WHERE City = '{0}' AND Rooms BETWEEN {1} AND {2}",
    Cities.Text, MinRooms.Text, MaxRooms.Text);
```

Don't ignore SQL injection issue...

Comment: Using `string.Format` is not a replacement for sql-parameters(just to clarify )